# Getting 200 Connection established in Charles but not able to see the response content for Https

Tags: ios, iphone, ssl, mocking, charles-proxy

Tried setup the Charles certificate from different blogs and can see the certificate is installed in device but getting 200 Connection established instead of proper response of Traffic

Comment: If you're trying to get it to work for the macOS itself, then you need to: 1. install the root cert 2. trust the cert by setting it to 'Always trust' 3. enable SSL proxy the hosts you'd like. I just do it for all hosts i.e.  `*` 4. have 'macOS proxy' enabled in Charles Proxy

Answer (score 1):

I had to do few extra steps to make Charles work in my ***Mac+iOS*** setup

If you are getting this error that mean you already have tried installing certificate. let's try reinstalling them once

**Step 1** : Remove all exiting certificate

`Settings > General > Profiles`
Check the certificate list for name starting with `Charles Proxy CA`
Click on the Charles certificate and Remove one by one using `Remove profile` option

***Step 2*** : Install new Charles certificate

***2.1*** : Charles (from Mac system) [Documentation](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/#:%7E:text=Launch%20Charles%20and%20go%20to,with%20Charles%20using%20SSL%20Proxying.) -> Help -> SSL Proxying -> Install Charles root certificate on a Mobile Device or Remote browser

Capture the IP and Port details

***2.2*** : Go to iOS device -> Settings ->Wi-Fi -> Click on the Connected network -> Select Configure Proxy in HTTP Proxy option -> Add IP in Server and Port as 8888 with Authentication off in device

***2.3*** : Open safari and browse chls.pro/ssl
Download the Certificate and install

***2.4*** : trust certificate in Settings > General > Profiles

***2.5*** : Toggle on the General > About > Certificate Trust Settings

Now, restart Charles. You should be able to see the traffic in Charles

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you follow the guideline to install the certificate and trust it on your iOS devices.

Majority people often forget trusting the Certifiacte in Setting app -> General -> About -> Certifiacte Trust Setting -> Switch ON on the certificate.

Proxyman has a built-in guideline that facilitates it.

Disclaimer: I create this app and hopefully it helps you to solve your problem.

[image: Install certificate on iOS device]